# Integrating JavaScript calendar in Angular project

Tags: javascript, angular, calendar

I'm trying to integrate this calendar https://codepen.io/Paul-DS/pen/JzOYmy in my angular project but I can't find a way to do it at the moment.
There's documentation on how to integrate with React and Vue but nothing with Angular.
Is it even possible ?

JavaScript

```
let tooltip = null;

const calendar = new Calendar('#calendar', {
  dataSource: function(year) {
    // Load data from GitHub API
    return fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:Paul-DS/bootstrap-year-calendar%20created:${year}-01-01..${year}-12-31`)
      .then(result => result.json())
      .then(result => {
        if (result.items) {
          return result.items.map(r => ({
            startDate: new Date(r.created_at),
            endDate: new Date(r.created_at),
            name: '#' + r.number + ' - ' + r.title,
            details: r.comments + ' comments'
          }));
        }
        
        return [];
      });
  },
  mouseOnDay: function(e) {
    if (e.events.length > 0) {
      var content = '';
                
      for (var i in e.events) {
        content += '<div class="event-tooltip-content">'
          + '<div class="event-name" style="color:' + e.events[i].color + '">' + e.events[i].name + '</div>'
                                      + '<div class="event-details">' + e.events[i].details + '</div>'
          + '</div>';
      }
      
      if (tooltip !== null) {
        tooltip.destroy();
        tooltip = null;
      }
      
      tooltip = tippy(e.element, {
          placement: 'right',
          content: content,
          animateFill: false,
          animation: 'shift-away',
          arrow: true
      });
      tooltip.show();
    }
  },
  mouseOutDay: function() {
    if (tooltip !== null) {
      tooltip.destroy();
      tooltip = null;
    }
  }
});
```

HTML
`<div id="calendar"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Definitely its possible to implement it on angular, however you need to edit that js code so it will work with angular.

Here check out the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-axkkkd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

to make a external api calls in angular you need a service component and use HttpClientModule to make a call and subscribe to the result from there you can apply any js code to it with.  The stack-blitz will make calls to your API and console log the obj in json format.

[Communicating with backend services using HTTP](https://angular.io/guide/http)